# Can I open .zip files created with split .zip.001 files without 7-zip?

Tags: compression, 7-zip, unzip, file-archiver

I use 7-zip to create several archives with fixed size (512 Mb) from one big file.
They have this structure:

```
my_name.zip.001
my_name.zip.002
...
my_name.zip.005
```

My problem is that without 7-zip I can't open them, is it possible by just using Windows 7 default tools?

Comment: If you only don't want to install the gui you can use the commandline version (http://www.7-zip.org/download.html) or google for "7zip portable version"

Answer (score 3):

On Windows 7:

1. Open the folder your split zip file is in
2. Shift + Right-click
3. "Open command prompt here"
4. Type `copy my_name.zip.* my_name.zip /b /v /y` and press Enter
5. Open your zip normally

This is beacuse 7-Zip doesn't split zip files according to the ZIP specification, but simply splits the binary file into smaller files, just like the GNU/Linux command `split`. `xcopy stuff.* stuff` will convert all the `stuff.001`, `stuff.002`... back into the original file.

Comment: `several archives with fixed size (512 Mb) from from one big file` My experience at Windows 7 is, that the on board unzipper runs in ressource problems or internal errors with such big files.

Comment: Did you try it? It just copy all my_name.zip.00X to the same my_name.zip file (rewriting).

Comment: My bad, I gave you the wrong command. You should use `copy` instead of `xcopy`.

Comment: Still not working.

Comment: Well now you surpirse me. Try adding `/b /v /y` after the command, to tell Windows you're using a binary file. If I remember correctly these are the switches I use when joining together archive files splitted with GNU-split.

Comment: And I am sure 7-zip uses GNU-split style to make multifile ZIPs, because I found that on their official website when I tried opening a multifile ZIP made with Linux `zip` command.

Comment: In windows 10 at least the command needs to be slightly different. The parameters need to be IN FRONT of the source. Thus copy /b /v /y my_name.zip.* my_name.zip

Comment: not working for me on windows 10. the copy works, but windows won't extract the files.  I'm trying to get the 7z portables onto this overly-protected machine.

Answer (score 1):

Sure!

Windows has a default zip uncompresser. Just right click on the file and unzip.
But if this doesn't work, you can always download Winrar. The procces is the same, right click on the file and click on the unzip option with winrar logo

Comment: I think the problem is that the zip file is split into parts. Not sure if the default windows unzip can handle that.

Comment: I does! Just select all of them and click the unzip option.

Comment: I can't see any menu on right click for default windows unzip.

Comment: Maybe extract? I do have it in other language so I dont know the exact english name